# How can i make the video has no index positions and no total length just like raw bitstream format, but it can have audio stream go along?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, edit, encode, bitstream

How can i make the video has no index positions and no total lenght,it cannot speed up slow down on a video player and it can have audio stream go along, with ffmpeg code?
I've research for a while but i only stuck at the way  to exact raw bitstream (annex B) video
Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem: what's the point of this?

Comment: The point is to make video has no timestamp and total length so we cannot speed up it on a media player(can only watch it at nomarl pace) and it can contain audio too

Comment: Can't find any raw muxer which can interleave streams.

Comment: Beside raw muxer.Are there any type of muxer that have no timestamp and have audio?

Comment: MXF, but they can be sped up.

Comment: I tested it but i can't add filters to the audio.Do you know why?

Comment: Show command you tried and its log.

Comment: Command:
 ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp4" -af "aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,aecho=0.8:0.88:5:0.85,aecho=0.8:0.88:5:0.85,atempo=1.55,highpass=500,treble=g=35" -ar 48000 -ac 2 output.mxf

Comment: Logs:

Output #0, mxf, to 'output.mxf':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
encoder         : Lavf58.19.100
 Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 702x572 [SAR 16:15 DAR 72:55], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2011-06-11T13:04:10.000000Z
encoder         : Lavc58.33.100 mpeg2video
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: The result show no changes on audio at all